# Django contrib message, not printing the Box label

Tags: python, html, django, message

I am new to Django, I built a little app, I want to display a message when I click a button. The message display correctly to the web app but it only show the text, it doesn't show  the color box (GREEN FOR SUCCESS, AND RED FOR ERROR). I searched a lot on the DOCS, and stackoverflow but didn't find a answer. Thanks you for helping

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ClientInfo
from django.contrib import messages

def send_sms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientInfo(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                sms = Client.messages.create(
                    from_="+XXXXXXXXXX",
                    body=mess,
                    to=sms_client
                )
                send = sms.sid

                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Succes! Message has been sent!')

            except:
                messages.error(request, 'Error! Message has not been sent!')
```

form.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 {% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
        {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}{% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <br>
    <button type="submit">ENVOYER</button>
    <br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'zfqh)_o&z_q_=yb)adwq&0gxe-aq4%n4ae8##^=*xyo#gleho6'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    'crispy_forms'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ALLOWED_HOST = ['*']
```

Comment: If you're just trying to format the message in your template, why not add an if statement? If the the message is successful you can have an element with one style and if not an element with a different style.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for answering, but I already have a IF stament. If it success or not the message is working, but i dont know how to add that box around the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I've left some parts out such as importing libraries in python and triggering the ajax request - let me know if you need those. Otherwise if you stick to this pattern you should be able to accomplish a lot with your Django app.

views.py:

```
# define behavior when requests are sent to 'send_message':
def SendMessage(request):

    # unpack request:
    status = request.POST['status']

    # set message depending on status:
    if status == True:
        message = 'Everything okay!'
    elif status == False:
        message = 'Something went wrong...'

    # pack context:
    context = json.dumps({
        'message' : message,
        'status' : status,
    })

    # return an HTTP response with context:
    return HttpResponse(context)
```

urls.py:

```
# route url to view function:
urlpatterns = [
    path('send_message/', views.SendMessage, name='send_message'),
]
```

template:

```
// create ajax request:    
$.ajax({

    // send to url:
    url : "{% url 'send_message' %}",
    type : 'POST',

    // add data to post request:
    data : {
        'status' : // status is either true or false based on some logic
    },
    dataType    :'json',

    // this function executes if we get a succesfull response from the backend:
    success : function(context) { 

        // get the value of 'status' and 'message' that was set in the backend:
        var status = context.status
        var message = context.message

        if (status) {/* do something if status is true */ }
        else {/* do something if status is false */}
    },
});
```

Comment: Ok - I recommend working with view functions instead of classes on the backend and using something like Ajax to send post requests on the frontend instead of submitting a form - this method is much more flexible - I'll provide an example shortly.

Comment: Edited my answer - let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: yes thank you but this i a litle bit complicted just to get the box. but thanks tho